# Why can SQLite not add up DECIMAL values?

Tags: sqlite

```
    sqlite> create table test (Qty DECIMAL(10,2));
    sqlite> insert into test values(1059.79);
    sqlite> insert into test values(-1050);
    sqlite> insert into test values(83.58);
    sqlite> insert into test values(130.51);
    sqlite> insert into test values(-5);
    sqlite> insert into test values(-136.68);
    sqlite> insert into test values(-2.6);
    sqlite> insert into test values(-75);
    sqlite> insert into test values(-4.6);
    sqlite> select sum(Qty) FROM TEST;
    -6.21724893790088e-14
```

Given that I explicitly specified DECIMAL(10,2) as the field type, why is the sum not 0?

Comment: Maybe it does not implement a fixed point arithmetic type, so is using floating point to perform the calculation? (It is Sql *Lite* after all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than messing about, and making my sql incompatible with the other databases I support, I merely wrote a user-defined replacement for the SQLite SUM function, like so:

```
[SqliteFunctionAttribute(Name = "SUM", Arguments = 1, FuncType = FunctionType.Aggregate)]
    class SqliteSum : SqliteFunction {
        public override void Step(object[] args, int stepNumber, ref object contextData) {
            if (args.Length < 1 || args[0] == null || args[0] == DBNull.Value)
                return;
            try {
                decimal d = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(args[0]), 4);
                if (contextData != null) d += (Decimal)contextData;
                contextData = d;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                WebServer.Log("Exception: {0}", ex);
            }
        }

        public override object Final(object contextData) {
            return contextData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that if you store the values as numbers in the DB, the numbers themselves will still be subjected to rounding and the precision limitations of floating-point values.

Comment: That's true - I have altered the code to correct any discrepancies (my DB sometimes stores numbers with up to 4 decimal places).

Answer (score 2):

SQLite does not have a `DECIMAL` type. Math is performed using 64-bit floating point values.

See [SQLite3 data types](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: So it is useless for financial applications. Is there an alternative sql database that does not require a server, works with c# on windows and linux, and is largely MySqll compatible?

Comment: @NikkiLocke Probably not. You could store the numbers as strings or blobs, and define some functions to do decimal operations on them.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does not have decimal type :

```
NULL
INTEGER
REAL
TEXT
BLOB
```

So maybe it is converted to Text , then suming happens.
SQLite is powerfull enough to work with, and can rely on for calculations and math, too.

Comment: <panto >Oh no it isn't</panto>. Not for accounting, which requires penny/cent accuracy.

Comment: But I am using it for finnancial apps, and it is good. Also there are other options, compare with MsSQL, that I like it. Any way about the calculation power I can trust it